# Loading new web page in an existing UIWebView

Tags: iphone

Hi any one help, am developing an iPhone application. In that I have face one functional module obstacles that I am in need to load more than one web link in a particular UIWebView as similar to iframe concept in web page, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use iframes?  The webview should render them properly.